# Node cannot find shared module in Yarn workspaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm attempting to set up a monorepo for a full-stack project using Node.js + Express on the backend and a React app frontend (with CRA).

I've so far set up Yarn workspaces with the following directory structure:

```
monorepo
  – package.json
  – packages
      – server
        – package.json
      – frontend
        – package.json
      – shared
        – package.json
```

I then do `yarn workspace frontend add shared` and `yarn workspace server add shared` and successfully find that the `shared` package is listed as a workspace dependency for `server` and `frontend` in `yarn list`

Furthermore, I am able to find the `shared` package inside of the `node_modules` of each of the workspaces.

The weird thing is, the `frontend` app is able to see the module fine when doing

```
import { foo } from "shared"
```

but the `backend` app is throwing the following error (with the exact same import statement as above):

```
Error: Cannot find module 'shared'
Require stack:
- /usr/src/app/dist/src/getApp.js
- /usr/src/app/dist/src/index.js
```

I have a suspicion that for some reason the backend app is not looking inside of `node_modules` for this package based on the require stack. I've tried various ways of modifying the import statement but continue to get the same error.

What's even stranger is that when running `ts-node` or `node` directly inside of the `server` directory, I'm able to import the module perfectly fine. It is only when I run the `server` app with `node dist/src/index.js` that it fails to find the dependency.

I have confirmed that the `package.json` file in the `shared` package is properly pointing to the right files for `main` and `types` and made sure that the dependent projects have `references` in their `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: For anyone having the same problem, this ended up being a problem with our Docker setup and had nothing to do with Node/Yarn. If you're having these issues, try making sure that your Docker container correctly has the symlink set up to the shared module. In our case, the symlink was set up properly (i.e., pointing to `../../shared`) but the shared directory itself was not included in our working directory as part of the build which led to Node not being able to find the module.

Comment: Hello Bryan, I am experiencing the same problem, could you please clarify in which directory symbolic link should be present? Taking your structure as example should it be in monorepo/packages/server? @Bryan